# karma: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I get the below error, whenever i try to inject my `service`.

```
(function () {

    describe('Test', function () {

        var $scope, $state, service,ctrl;

        beforeEach(function() {
            module('moduleApp');

            module(function($provide) {
                $provide.service('AppService', service);
            });

            inject(function($rootScope,$injector,$controller,AppService) {
                $scope = $rootScope.$new();
                $state = $injector.get('$state');
                service = $injector.get('AppService');
                ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {
                    $scope: $scope,
                    $state: $state,
                    AppService: service
                });
            });
        });


        it('should have a working UserSession service', function() {
            expect(service).to.exist;
        });


    });

}());
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.instantiate (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4577:82)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4438:24)
    at Object.invoke (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4570:17)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4422:37)
    at Object.invoke (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4570:17)
    at bower_components/angular/angular.js:4387:37
    at getService (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4529:39)
    at Object.invoke (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4561:13)
    at Context.workFn (bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2524:20)
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2496:37)
Error: Declaration Location
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2489:25)
    at Context.<anonymous> (test/unit/app/views/Test.js:17:13)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do?! First you tell karma to use an undefined object `service` as `AppService` and then you try to get `AppService` from injector and assign it to `service`? It's a loop.

If the unit under test is `AppService`, there is no need for this:

```
module(function($provide) {
    $provide.service('AppService', service);
});
```

if you need the service, you can simply do this:

```
inject(function($rootScope,$injector,$controller, _AppService_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $state = $injector.get('$state');
    service = _AppService_;
    ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {
        $scope: $scope,
        $state: $state,
        AppService: service
    });
});
```

and if the unit under test depends on `AppService`, you first build a mock service and then use `provide`, and remember you don't need to inject it again.

Comment: should my controller hold the reference for AppService like below... ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {
                    $scope: $scope,
                    $state: $state,
                    AppService: service
                });

Comment: @Shane I updated my answer. take a look at it and let me know if you still got problem.